# Getting WordPress Gallery to work in external PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, external, shortcode

I am developing a custom site and I am pulling in data from a wordpress backend to display on my page.  The page that I am developing is completely outside of the wordpress directory.  So far I have figured out a way to get the content to display on my page, however if the content has a gallery in it, the gallery doesn't display correctly on my page.  What I see is the shortcode text `[gallery ids="35,29"]`.  I am assuming that I need to include some functions or some other files in order to get my page to render the shortcode correctly?  Here is what I have in my file so far:

At the top of my file:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp/wp-config.php');
//get_header();
function get_content($id) {

$post = get_page($id);
$content = apply_filters('get_the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;

}
?>
```

then in the page I have the code to display the content:

```
<?php get_content(25); ?>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to allow the shortcode to filter through it's own handler's and functions.  This will return the formatted content.

Replace 'get_the_content' with 'the_content' and running that through do_shortcode.

Comment: I tried that but I need it to be dynamic because the shortcode is inside the post.

Comment: I tried that and it displays the same thing    [gallery ids="35,29"]

Comment: Try this? `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="35,29"]'); ?>`

Comment: That works but I need to have it dynamic so that will allow the shortcode to be inline in the content.  Thanks for your help Brandon... I totally appreciate your time!

Comment: Here is the site I'm working on for your reference: http://delortomusic.com/mike/

Comment: You're more than welcome for my time :)  Try replacing 'get_the_content' with ''the_content' and running that through do_shortcode?

Comment: That worked!! Now on to trying to get the lightbox and css working. ;)  hopefully that is a little easier.  Thanks again for your help Brandon!

Comment: You're welcome!  If it worked exactly how you wanted, please mark the answer as "accepted" :)